# Dropdown ngModel is undefined until change made

Tags: angular

Using Angular 5, I created a dropdown with options that are being populated with data from Firebase. Even though the options are populated, my ngModel is undefined unless I change the option. What can I do to make this work with the default option without changing to another first?

Here is the HTML:

```
<select name="reviewer" [(ngModel)]="reviewer">
  <option *ngFor="let editor of editors" [ngValue]="editor.$value">{{editor.$value}}</option>
</select>
```

Here is the TS:

```
export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {

  reviewer;

  constructor(...) {

    alert(this.reviewer); //undefined unless changed to another option

  }

}
```

Comment: You have to initialize `reviewer` to the default item of the `editors` array (in `ngOnInit` or as soon as the array is filled).

Comment: See this section, https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#caveat-option-selection

Comment: declare the variable as: reviever:string=""; or reviever:number=0;

Answer (score 0):

In angular life-cycle constructor is executed first. Its executed before the initialization of the view. In your code you have used this.reviewer in the constructor and at that time your variable haven't initialized yet. So it gives an undefined value.
But once you change the drop-down value a new value will be assigned to the reviewer variable because of [(ngModel)] data binding.

If you have assigned a default value to the reviewer variable on declaration of the variable or before the alert it wont give an undefined value.

For example :

```
export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {

  reviewer;

  constructor(...) {
   this.reviewer=editors[0] //you can assign a default value here
    alert(this.reviewer); //undefined unless changed to another option

  }

}
```

read about angular life cycle from here

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks[image]